# Nodejs with forever issue in VPS, forever command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

I am new to NodeJS. I tried using my node js application in my local machine, with installing forever module, script runs continuously
But when I deploy my application in VPS(Godaddy). Node application runs fine. I tried installing forever inorder to run my script continuously, with command

```
npm install forever -g.
```

It installs the module but when trying to run it with command

```
forever start app.js
```

says forever command not found.
Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at where forever was installed and then see if you have a path to that directory?

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to check that?

Comment: What OS is your GoDaddy VPS?

Comment: @jfriend00 Its CentOS 6

Comment: I'm not an experienced Linux guy myself, but a little work with Google shows this http://www.wikihow.com/Find-a-File-in-Linux and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps

Answer (score 2):

You should check with `npm list -g` if the module is listed.

Other way to check it is to go to a bash console and type `ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules | grep forever` and check if the module is there.

If it's not there, something went wrong installing the module. Install it again with `sudo npm install -g forever`.

Check with `printenv | egrep -o "(.*node*)` in the bash console and see if you have "NODE_PATH=/opt/lib/node_modules".

If not `export NODE_PATH=/opt/lib/node_modules` int the console and try again the forever command `forever start app.js`.